# Can't npm start on my react project after adding babel-cli

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, mern, npm-start

Miks@DESKTOP-DOAIF41 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/LYNDA MERN/Exercise Files/Ch02/02_01/start/dist
$ npm start

> react-essential@1.0.0 start c:\Users\mctumbaga\Desktop\LYNDA MERN\Exercise Files\Ch02\02_01\start
>   httpster -d ./dist -p 3000

'httpster' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-essential@1.0.0 start: `httpster -d ./dist -p 3000`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-essential@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mctumbaga\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-18T02_15_26_741Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I see above that your error states:

> 'httpster' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Have you tried installing the package globally `npm -g install httpster` so that `httpster` is accessible from any directory where you want to have an HTTP service running?